# Занесение значений из аякс запроса в объект в jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, массивы, объекты

Здравствуйте. Не могу понять в чем загвоздка. Пишу простую функцию, как на примере ниже:

```
function setCookie(val)
{
    var arr = new Object();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'index.php',
        data:
        {
            val: val,

            query: 'set-cookie'
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
            // тут возвращается, как и должно, число и без массивов: 100
            console.log(data);
            // заношу в объект число, которое пришло с запроса
            arr = { 'data': data };
        }
    });

    // в итоге мне возвращается: Object {} undefined
    console.log(arr, arr['data']);
    return arr;
}
```

Значение теряются при занесении в объект. Как занести в объект то, что пришло с запроса? Вроде в верху создал нужную глобальную переменную, а результат никакой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так ничего не выйдет.
Код асинхронный, т. е. выполняется не сразу, а... когда-то в будущем.
Для этого можно использовать `Promise`:

```js
function setCookie(val)
{
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // Оборачиваем код в обещание
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'index.php',
        data:
        {
            val: val,
            query: 'set-cookie'
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
            // тут возвращается, как и должно, число и без массивов: 100
            console.log(data);
          
            resolve({ 'data': data });
        }
    });
  });
}

setCookie(value).then(res => {
  console.info(res); // { 'data': 100 }
});
```

Но это больше на костыль (работающий, но костыль) похоже, в `ES2017` обещают `Async/Await` - это уже лучше.

Comment: Спасибо, я завтра гляну, что получится.

Comment: Вот только для полноценного использования `Promise` и функций-стрелок автору вопроса придется подключать полифилл и транслировать код с помощью `babel`. Хотя для решения проблемы достаточно вернуть из функции `setCookie` результат выполнения команды `$.ajax(...)`, к которому во внешней среде так же можно приписать обработчик с помощью `.then` http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

Comment: @КонстантинБашаркевич, jQuery имеет свою реализацию promise, поэтому никакие полифиллы в данном случае не нужны, как впрочем и явное использование нативных промисов

Comment: @Grundy ну так я о ней и говорю =)

Comment: Подскажите как её вызывать со своими значениями, что-то у меня не получается. Вариант, setCookie.then('...'); не работает.

Comment: @J.Doe `setCookie.then('...');` не работает потому что должно быть `setCookie(val).then('...');`, а вообще рекомендую обратить внимание на мой комментарий выше.

Comment: @КонстантинБашаркевич теперь понял, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Похоже дело в том что код является асинхронным и в переменную ещё и в правду нечего не записано, но можно сделать синхронный запрос добавив

`async: false,`

после

`url: 'index.php',`

но тогда вкладка на момент запроса будет "**заблокирована**" и не будет выполнятся какой либо код до **завершения запроса**, лучше писать асинхронный код но его писать тяжелее.

Comment: Спасибо, я завтра гляну, что получится.